# rails using rjs prototype conflict with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails rjs, but I found it doesn't work, when I added "jquery.js" like this

`<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults,'jquery.validate.min.js'%>`

but when I changed it like this

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults%>
```

It works, so weird! any helps? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Standard rjs works with prototype javascript library which ships with rails by default. When you added `javascript_include_tag :defaults`, you included this library (look at result html).

You can use remote javascript with JQuery. View this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery) how to do it.
The best practice for now is to use unobtrusive javascript. Another screencast on this subject [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript). And it works not only with rails 3 but [with rails 2.3 as well](http://andrewcox.org/post/507032751/rails-3-0-unobtrusive-ajax-in-rails-2-3-x).